# PHPStorm, Silex DI indices code completion

Tags: dependency-injection, phpstorm, code-completion, silex, service-locator

I'm trying `PHPStorm` and have trouble with its code completion. I write project with `Silex` framework and faced PHPStorm's lack of code completion for `Silex` dependency injection container. For example, it doesnt codecomplete `$app['twig']->` or `$app['db']->` or any other service. The only way solution I've found is to do smth like this

```
$db = $app['db'];
/** @var $db \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection */
$db->....
```

And then `PHPStorm` will do code completion. Services are registered using ServiceProvider interface.
Is there a way to make PHPStorm do code completion in such cases without additional vars and comments?

Comment: Just so you know, PhpStorm cannot do it yet, but no other IDE I know of does that.

Comment: Yup. But I found a PhpStorm plugin named "Magicento" bringing nice completion/navigate/etc features for Magento-based projects. I'm goinng to test the plugin (have watched usage videos only) and if it works good there is a way to widen completion capabilities (but with additional hotkey) in many ways.

Comment: ArrayAccess is what annoyed me about Pimple, which is why I wrote [Props](https://github.com/mrclay/Props), a basic DIC based on __get and __call

Comment: You don't want to use DI this way... If you want to use $db for example in one of your Model classes, then you have to do something like this: `$model = new Model(); $model->setDbConnection($app['db']);` after this you'll have autocomplete...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this is currently not possible, however, there is currently work going on to add support for generic factory patterns, see this issue on their issue-tracker:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6027

The PhpStorm developers welcome new feature requests on their issue tracker and are quite responsive. So you may file a feature request

Also, this may be related to your question:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5304

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin for PHPStorm / Intellij IDEA:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7809?pr=

Didn't tried it yet, but looks promising...

Edit: Just gave it a quick shot, and it looks really cool and simple to set up:

- Install the plugin via the IDE plugin manager
- Add the following dependency:

> ```
> "require": {
>     "sorien/silex-pimple-dumper": "~1.0"
> }
> ```

- Register the provider:

  $app->register(new Sorien\Provider\PimpleDumpProvider());

And you are done.